# Xcode 8.3.2 Clang Error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to update one of my project, when I opened it I performed validated settings, but when I try to build it I just face with this error :

> Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group : clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

with no more infos and I am not using cocoapods or any external frameworks. I just searched everywhere and did any possible solution such as :

- Clean and run
- Searched for duplicate files
- Check imported header files
- Delete xxxTest
- Checked Build Active architecture
- Validated Settings
- Checked missing frameworks
- Restart mac
- Changed iOS deployment target
- Disabled bitcode

and etc...

Is there anything to solve this issue ?!

Comment: disable bitcode.

Comment: @KKRocks Fortget to mention that !!! I did

Comment: well. execute the linker with -v -- you can do so via terminal

Comment: @Daij-Djan How ?

Comment: Right-click the error in the the Issue Navigator. Choose "Reveal in Log" and show us the actual error message.

Comment: well it's a stretch but referencing an uninitialized static field can also cause linking error

Comment: I imagine that you already did, but did you delete derived data?

Comment: @TheNextman Thanks this worked !! please post it as answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right-click the error in the the Issue Navigator. Choose "Reveal in Log" or "Reveal in Project Navigator "and see the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

-Try this 
1.Xcode -> Preferences -> Location -> click on derived data path and clear all derived data.
2."Build Phases" -> "Compile Sources" and look for duplicate of classes.
3.Or check if you have "*.m" files in your #import

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I forget to update my submodules (Carthage in my case). After I update my submodules I didn't get the error.